# How to get CME User Preferences language within XPM WebsiteFrame

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

I have built what I call an Edition Panel for XPM that basically using a C# TBB creates some HTML+JS with XPM markup and enables full component edition.

I want to vary some things of the Edition Panel based on the user preferences language of the CME so I need to know the language of the CME **within the website** frame while editing from XPM.

I figured out some hacks to get it:

- I could create a dummy SiteEdit extension with some .resx files with a `lang`
  key inside and the current language as value. This will be
  loaded into `Tridion.LocalizedStrings` that is available on the website
  when it's been edited with XPM.
- Also I started to think about extending Anguilla's security restrictions at 
  `Tridion.Web.UI.SiteEdit.EditorXDMHandler`, aka `$sexdm`, to allow
  `Tridion.Utils.CrossDomainMessaging` to send this information back to
  the website when required, but I'm not sure if this is feasible.

Although I figured out this hacks I want to know if there is a **proper way** (or best/simple/elegant way) to share this information with the external website or I'm about to commit a horrible sin.

Thank you.